# DbContext does not contain a definition for 'Connection' error using transaction Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, transactions, connection

I need to use a transaction in Entity Framewok (version 5) in a controller of an MVC4 project.
This because I've to save data in different table within the same transaction and avoid data inconsistency..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;    using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Objects;

 private DBcontextName context = new DBcontextName ();

 context.Connection.Open();
```

When i try to use transaction, the object Connection is not recognized by context

DbContext does not contain a definition for 'Connection' and no extension method 'Connection' accepting a first argument of type...

I don't understand what it's wrong,
can you help me please?

```
namespace NameSpaceName    {
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Data.Objects;
    using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class DBcontextName : DbContext
    {
        public DBcontextName ()
            : base("name=DBcontextName ")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet......{ get; set; }
        public DbSet......{ get; set; }

               }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (DBcontextName context = new DBcontextName()
    {
        SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)((EntityConnection)context.ObjectContext.Connection).StoreConnection;

            using (SqlCommand command = storeConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection ;
                connection.Open();

                command.CommandText = yourStoredProcedureName;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.AddRange(yourSqlParameters);

                using (DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // Do stuff
                }
            }
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

You only need to do this if you are calling a stored procedure though (for speed with multiple records, you could have a proc taking a table-valued parameter to save a list of records). If you just want to use entity framework, you can do this:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (DBcontextName context = new DBcontextName()
    {
        // Get objects, delete objects, add objects, etc.
        // Or add new objects
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can I use Transaction Scope if i have to do multiple save changes (to get the identity from one table and use it in another)? And how can I rollback in case of error?

Comment: Yes, you can. Sorry, I forgot to add the call to scope.Complete() at the end of the TransactionScope using statement, which would indicate that you are done and want to commit the transaction. Any errors that happen before this point would cause the transaction to be rolled back. This is assuming that the transaction scope created the transaction (in this case it would have). Here is some more documentation on TransactionScope.Complete() and error handling including an example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete.aspx